# Junit trying to confirm Null is returned

Tags: java, junit

I have this extra credit assignment that makes me do junit test but I don't understand how I can make my test for getDestinations return null.
So I have this methods and variable:

```
private final Point3D destination = new Point3D();

public Point3D getDestination() {
        if (destination == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return new Point3D(destination);
    }


public final void setDestination(Point3D aPoint) throws InvalidDataException {
        if (aPoint == null) {
            throw new InvalidDataException("Null Point3D sent to setDestination(Point3D)");
        }
        setDestination(aPoint.getX(), aPoint.getY(), aPoint.getZ());
    }
```

I'm trying to make netbeans know that I when I test for `destination = null` it returns null.

Hers my test so far:

```
   public void testGetDestination(){
        testPoint3D = new Point3D(4.0, 5.0, 6.0);
        Point3D p = testMovable.getDestination();
        assertEquals(p, testPoint3D);
        assertNotNull(p); 
    }
   public void testSetDestination_Point3D() throws Exception {
        Point3D newPoint = new Point3D(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        testMovable.setDestination(newPoint);
        Point3D p = new Point3D();
        assertNotNull(p);
        assertEquals(p, newPoint);
        assertNotSame(p, newPoint);
        p = null;
        try{
            testMovable.setDestination(p);
            fail("Null Point3D sent to setDestination(Point3D)");
        }catch(InvalidDataException ex){ 
            assertEquals(ex.getMessage(),"Null Point3D sent to setDestination(Point3D)");
        }
    }
```

but as you can see I can't really invoke a null without having it to fail/caught by exceptions.

Is there a way to go about this?

Comment: Why are you trying to test an impossible situation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there's no way to cause `destination` to be `null`, given your current code. Specifically:

```
private final Point3D destination = new Point3D();
```

The `final` modifier makes it impossible for `destination` to ever be assigned to any other value besides the `Point3D` it's initialized to.

Thus in your `getDestination()` method, the following code can never be reached and should be removed:

```
    if (destination == null) {
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: It's a pleasure. Glad that helped :)